# When is it appropriate to use a "well" UI element?

Tags: website-design, gui-design

Are there standard uses for it?

I see it most often when embedding example code...

As see on Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#misc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a `well` element because it visually sinks into the surface of the page, like a well sinks into the surface of the landscape. It suggests that there is a (grey) level below the (white) one you're looking at currently.

Most appropriate uses therefore would be to show something that is a subset of what you're currently seeing, eg navigation for the next level down, or more details of the thing you describe. It should not be required to read the `well` content to make sense of the page therefore, it merely adds information that can easily be skipped. This could work for a block of code, but not so much for a block quote.

Don't overuse the effect though. A `well` should take up only little space on the page, and not be repeated often on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard the term `well` used for that. Huh. Maybe it's a Twitter term. Visually, I call it a box. Or maybe a frame. In terms of semantics, well context is everything. It could be used as a call out. Or a heading style. Or a block quote. Or, as in the example, a block of code.

It's appropriate to use it whenever it makes sense for you to use it...likely to emphasize or highlight some content.